Real-life interpretations of a Miklos Schweitzer problem
This is P8 from the 2002 Miklós Schweitzer competition:

Given $n$ points in general position. Show that one can color these points using at most $c\log n$ colors for some constant $c$, so that any disk in the plane containing at least one point from the set intersects some color class exactly once.

I’m not asking for a solution, but rather a real life cool interpretation of this problem, because I’m willing to give a presentation about this problem. I was thinking of seeing this as a cursor pointing at some cluster of points, and this problem as the number of colors needed so that cursor has at least a unique choice to choose from. It would be helpful to see if it reminds others of things (whatever: cartoons, real life situation, or something you imagine…) that would be seen as applications of this problem.

Maybe there are some issues in translation (or maybe it is just me) , but I am not able to see what the claim is , mathematically or otherwise. It seems highly ambiguous (or trivially true) to me.

@Prem you can check the problem and a solution here: https://dgrozev.wordpress.com/2023/01/25/delaunay-triangulation-a-miklos-schweitzer-problem/

I did see that earlier & I see that the Original was in Hungarian & I thought that translation might have occurred. Some Issues I see (1) It says Points in General Position : In Plane or Space ? Later , Disk is in Plane (2) What is color class (3) What counts as Single Intersection ? (3A) a very thin Ellipse can cut a Circle into 3 Pieces : is that Single Intersection or 4 Intersections ? (3B) When 2 Closed Curves cross , there will be at least 2 Intersections : Is that counted as 1 ? (3C) When 2 Closed Curves touch tangentially , is that counted as $0$ ? (4) Can we color all with 1 color ?
